# Convert ISO 8601 to unixtimestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp, date-format, time-format

How can I convert
`2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00` (ISO 8601) to `1326883500` (unixtimestamp) in PHP?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This code converts an ISO 8601 datetime to a Unix timestamp in UTC.

```php
echo date("U",strtotime('2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00'));
```

longer version:

```php
$dateTime = new DateTime('2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00');
$dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$utcTimestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
echo $utcTimestamp;
```

Comment: @Codler in this case no. i thought you may want to use another format of input/output

Answer (score 22):

#### To convert from ISO 8601 to unixtimestamp :

```
strtotime('2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00');
// Output : 1326883500
```

---

#### To convert from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (timezone server) :

```
date_format(date_timestamp_set(new DateTime(), 1326883500), 'c');
// Output : 2012-01-18T11:45:00+01:00
```

#### To convert from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (GMT) :

```
date_format(date_create('@'. 1326883500), 'c') . "\n";
// Output : 2012-01-18T10:45:00+00:00
```

#### To convert from unixtimestamp to ISO 8601 (custom timezone) :

```
date_format(date_timestamp_set(new DateTime(), 1326883500)->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')), 'c');
// Output : 2012-01-18T05:45:00-05:00
```

Comment: Very useful! Thanks much!